# Limit of a ratio of two similar binomial coefficients with two variables

Tags: combinatorics, limits, binomial-coefficients

Consider two rational numbers $a, b > 0$. What can be said of the following limit as a function of $a, b$, where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers?

$$
L = \lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}\dfrac{
    \displaystyle\binom{x + y}{x}
}{
    \displaystyle\binom{ax + by}{ax}
}
$$

For reasons that I will show below, I make two claims:

> **Claim 1.**
>
> - If both $a, b > 1$ then $L = 0$
> - If both $a, b < 1$ then $L = \infty$
>
> **Claim 2.** If $a < 1$ and $b > 1$ (or vice versa), the limit is undefined, i.e., there are two different sequences of $(x,y)$ approaching infinity such that the first yields $0$ and the second yields $\infty$.

**The question: Are the claims above true?** (If yes, how to prove them?)

*Note: Since both $x$ and $y$ are going to infinity, we can assume that both $ax$ and $by$ are integers. Also, the edge case of $a = b = 1$ can be ignored.*

---

## My reasoning

Define $f(u, v) = \displaystyle\binom{u + v}{u} = \displaystyle\binom{u + v}{v}$. Applying the approximation $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k} \approx \dfrac{n^k}{k!}$, we get:

$$f(u, v) \approx \dfrac{(u+v)^u}{u!} \approx \dfrac{(u+v)^v}{v!}$$

Now, assuming that only $x$ goes to infinity:

$$\begin{align}
L_X
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f(ax,by)}
\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
\dfrac{
    \dfrac{(x+y)^y}{y!}
}{
    \dfrac{(ax+by)^{by}}{(by)!}
}
\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
\dfrac{
    (x+y)^y
}{
    (ax+by)^{by}
}
\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
\dfrac{x^y}{(ax)^{by}}
\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
\dfrac{x^y}{a^{by}x^{by}}
\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
\dfrac{x^y}{x^{by}}
\\\\&= \lim_{x\to\infty}
x^{y(1-b)}
\\\\&= 
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\infty \quad \text{ if $b$ < 1} \\ 
0\,\,\, \quad \text{ if $b$ > 1}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}$$

Analogously, assuming that only $y$ goes to infinity, we get:

$$
L_Y = \lim_{y\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x,y)}{f(ax,by)} = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\infty \quad \text{ if $a$ < 1} \\ 
0\,\,\, \quad \text{ if $a$ > 1}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The observations above suggest to me, intuitively, that $a > 1$ "pulls" $L$ to zero and so do $b > 1$. This way, if both $a, b > 1$, probably $L = 0$ and if both $a, b < 1$, probably $L = \infty$.

And, in turn, if one of them is greater than $1$ and the other is less than $1$, probably it is possible to choose a certain way to approach infinity that will yield $0$, and another way that will yield $\infty$, therefore making $L$ itself undefined.